# Bootstrap v5 text-only Carousel keep size of biggest text item (responsive)

Tags: css, carousel, bootstrap-5

I am working on a Bootstrap v5 text-only Carousel.
My text items are populating dynamically, and I don't know their sizes beforehand.

I code the text in carousel-caption element, and remove the img.

My problem : the indicators+controls are moving up and down depending on the text items sizes.
I want the indicators+controls to be fixed (relative to the carousel, not to the text items). And I want them to let enough space for the biggest item text.

What I found :

- BS 5 is coding hidden carousel item as `rotateY(180deg); backface-visibility:hidden;`
- so, if I force `visibility:hidden` instead, then it works: the biggest text item fill its place, and is hidden
- but the animation is not as good. The text slides, then disappears.

So my question is :

- is there a simple way to get the original animation with my solution?
  or
- is there a way to keep the place for the biggest item with the original BS5 solution?

The solution must work responsively on big screen as well as on mobile screen.

```css
.carousel {
  min-height: auto;
}

.carousel-inner {
  margin: auto;
}

.carousel-item {
  display: block;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.carousel-item.active {
  display: block;
  visibility: visible;
}

.carousel-caption {
  color: black;
  top: 50%;
  position: static;
}

.carousel-indicators {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.carousel-indicators .active {
  background-color: black;
}

.carousel-control-prev,
.carousel-control-next {
  width: 49%;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.carousel-control-prev>span,
.carousel-control-next>span {
  color: black;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div id="slider" class="carousel slide" data-bs-interval="false">
  <div class="carousel-indicators">
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#slider" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#slider" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#slider" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active text-center p-2">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
          dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item text-center p-2">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <p> Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem
          quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam
          eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit
          qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item text-center p-2">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <p>-Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem
          quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam
          eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit
          qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam,
          eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi
          nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum
          exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas
          nulla pariatur?</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#slider" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span>prev</span>
  </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#slider" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span>next</span>
  </button>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Thanks !!

Comment: I don't understand why the snippet is not running :-/ I am doing something wrong